How to automatically assign Material in slot to generated mesh from Geometry Node
Currently the Set Material node must select the Material manually from the dropdown can’t set by index.

the only know if want to automatically set material from slot to the generated Mesh its switch the link from Mesh to Object

but i want it automatically assigned to the generated mesh without switching the link Material
Is it possible?

Do you want a material assigned to the mesh based on the mesh index, so that the index of the mesh means it gets a material with this index, or do you want to assign a material to a mesh by manually choosing an index instead of setting a specific material?

This question is similar to: How do I switch multiple materials in the geometry node editor with the new index switch node?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

its doesn't matter about the index i just want the (any) material in the slot is automatically assigned to the generated mesh,
and i think my question is clear enough,
and i already accepted the answer,
thank you

Join with old geometry, set the material index, and delete old geometry (it's important to avoid shifting old geometry material indices, therefore it has to be first in the "Join Geometry" node):

For multiple materials (bottom "Capture Attribute" stores chosen material index):

